# Como plotar gráficos usando a QCustomPlot na main thread?

Tags: qt

Gostaria de saber como plotar os dados da porta serial na biblioteca QcustomPlot para ficar atualizando. Desde já agradeço a compreensão.

```
void serialThread::run(){

mutex.lock(); 

 if(serial->waitForReadyRead(1)){

  QByteArray data = serial->readAll();

     qDebug () << data;

 }
   mutex.unlock();
 }
```

Comment: O que é o método run? Como isso se relaciona com o título?

Comment: Eu preciso plotar gŕaficos através de thread, só que eu não sei como usar a thread principal, pois a biblioteca QCustomPlot não permite a plotagem de gráficos fora da thread principal e eu não sei como fazer a plotagem dos gráficos na thread principal!

Comment: Agora, o que você tentou fazer e qual foi o problema que aconteceu? Meramente chamar a biblioteca não faz a plotagem na thread principal? Aconteceu algum erro? -- Me desculpe estar sendo *chato*, mas para você o problema é claro, mas não está passando o problema de forma clara para nós. Eu realmente ainda não entendi o que você quer.

Comment: @NetinhoSantos Seria legal postar o código que tem até agora, senão fica um jogo de adivinhação para te ajudar. Da forma como está a pergunta, não dá para entender em qual das etapas do desenvolvimento está sua dificuldade. Perceba que com mais informações podemos ajudar melhor e mais objetivamente. Para acrescentar detalhes, basta você clicar em **[edit]** logo embaixo do texto da pergunta original.

Answer (score 5):

## Usando QCustomPlot para plotar:

A classe `QCustomPlot` herda de `QWidget` e por tanto opera sempre na thread principal. Um exemplo extraido diretamente da [documentação](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/tutorials/basicplotting):

```
// generate some data:
QVector<double> x(101), y(101); // initialize with entries 0..100
for (int i=0; i<101; ++i)
{
  x[i] = i/50.0 - 1; // x goes from -1 to 1
  y[i] = x[i]*x[i]; // let's plot a quadratic function
}
// create graph and assign data to it:
customPlot->addGraph();
customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
// give the axes some labels:
customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("x");
customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("y");
// set axes ranges, so we see all data:
customPlot->xAxis->setRange(-1, 1);
customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, 1);
customPlot->replot();
```

Onde o `customPlot` é um `QCustomPlot` criado anteriormente.

---

## Sobre como plotar fora da main thread:

Por, na minha opinião, uma falha de design da biblioteca, a classe responsável por exibir o gráfico na tela é a mesma responsável por renderizar o gráfico em si. Ou seja, ao mesmo tempo que ela realiza processamento intensivo, ela herda de `QWidget`, que **não pode ser criado fora da main thread**.

Dessa forma tem alguma opções não tão boas:

1. Criar um programa externo que recebe parâmetros na linha de comando e então renderiza o gráfico usando o widget. Repare que você não precisa chamar a função `exec()` da aplicação, então esse processo termina imediatamente após renderizar e salvar o gráfico. Então, do seu programa principal, execute este passando os parâmetros que precisa e aguardando terminação. Pode usar `QProcess` para isso. Repare que infelizmente ainda será preciso criar uma `QApplication` lá, provocando o carregamento de toda a estrutura de exibição do Qt.
2. Tomar uma atitude mais agressiva e editar a biblioteca removendo a dependencia do `QWidget`. Funciona, mas é não é bem algo ideal e vai causar muito trabalho não relacionado ao seu programa em si. Além do risco de provocar novos bugs, e de ter todo um retrabalho quando lançarem novas versões.

Se for tomar o caminho 2, sugiro contribuir suas alterações para o repositório deles, melhorando a biblioteca como um todo e tirando o peso de você dar manutenção ao código.

Comment: Guilherme, a minha pergunta é como eu poderia usar a main thread para plotar os gráficos já que a QcustomPlot não permite plotar fora dela.

Comment: Ou entã estou pensando seriamente em procurar outro meio para essa tarefa. A porta serial já estou fazendo a leitura e configurando os parâmetros. O programa tem que se conectar ao arduino, ler os dados dos sensores e plotar os gráficos.

Comment: "como eu poderia usar a main thread para plotar os gráficos já que a QcustomPlot não permite plotar fora dela". Você quer ou não quer usar a main thread?

Comment: Rsrsrsrsrs Sim!

Comment: Er. "Sim" significa que você quer usar ou "Sim" significa que você não quer usar?

Comment: @NetinhoSantos Por favor, edite e clarifique sua pergunta com exatamente o que você quer fazer. Não está claro sua intenção.

Comment: Sim! Eu quero usar a thread principal

Comment: @NetinhoSantos Então qual é o problema? A biblioteca já usa a thread principal por padrão. Novamente: edite e deixe sua pergunta clara. Evite responder aqui no comentário. Edite a pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal meio off o que vou perguntar: se criar o gráfico em uma outra thread, e então mover para thread principal e re-parentar o objeto, não funciona? Seriam os métodos `moveToThread` e `setParent`. Não sei como a `QCustomPlot` funciona, mas, com outros controles isso funciona.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira infelizmente não pois `QCustomPlot` herda de `QWidget`, que não pode sair da main thread.